# How to properly export to CSV in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, csv, export-to-csv

I have a JavaScript function that enables me to download a CVS file. When I open this file in excel, everything is placed in the same column instead.

This is my code:

```
function convertToCSV(dataArray) {
   var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

   dataArray.forEach(function(infoArray, index)
   {
      dataString = infoArray.join(",");
      csvContent += index < dataArray.length ? dataString+ "\n" : dataString;
   }); 

   var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
   var link = document.createElement("a");
   link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
   link.setAttribute("download", "download.csv");
   document.body.appendChild(link);
   link.click();
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Output]

This is the output I'm expecting:

[image: desired output]

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

NB: I have been looking for a way to export straight to an .xlsx or .xls file, but I didn't win.

Comment: This may help: https://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel

Comment: I guess your delimite character is ";" instead of ",". Try to use dataString = infoArray.join(";"); instead. Unfortunately this goes by region configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **mongo-xlsx** module to export your data to xlsx file

```
var mongoXlsx = require('mongo-xlsx');
var data=dataArray;
var model=mongoXlsx.buildDynamicModel(data);
mongoXlsx.mongoData2Xlsx(data, model, function(err, data) {
console.log("data",data);
console.log('File saved as:', data.fullPath); 
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with native js fairly easily like so:

```
let text = '';
dataArray.map(arr => text += arr.join(',') + '\r\n');

let link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(text)); 
link.setAttribute('download', 'download.csv');
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```